# Why are sealed attributes slower to fetch than unsealed with GetCustomAttribute<T>()?

Tags: c#, performance, attributes, code-analysis, ndepend

I was running my code through NDepend tonight and had a rule violation that has me a bit perplexed. The rule quotes the following from MSDN:

> The .NET Framework class library provides methods for retrieving
>   custom attributes. By default, these methods search the attribute
>   inheritance hierarchy; for example Attribute.GetCustomAttribute
>   searches for the specified attribute type, or any attribute type that
>   extends the specified attribute type. Sealing the attribute eliminates
>   the search through the inheritance hierarchy, and can improve
>   performance.

I have a validation base class that takes validation rules (attributes) and processes them to ensure a property on the instance meets a certain criteria. When the class is instanced, it runs through and caches all of the `PropertyInfo's` and validation `attributes` that will be ran through later. The cache is a static Dictionary so each subsequent instance just pulls from the dictionary. I then call a `ValidateAll()` method on the class that iterates through all of the `PropertyInfo's` and their associated attributes and invokes a `Validate()` method on them.

I created a Fixture and a unit test to iterate over 1,000 instances. The test was performed with my validation rules being both sealed and unsealed. The unsealed tests ran faster than the sealed, which has me a bit confused. At the least I expected them to run at the same speed, but not slower.

1. Unsealed Attributes: 41.3199ms
2. Sealed Attributes: 42.6241ms (using `GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true)`)
3. Sealed Attributes: 43.3881ms (using `GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ValidationAttribute), false)`)

The two times are an average over 5 different tests for both sealed and unsealed.

The following is the unit test. I included the initial instancing of objects in my timer as that is where the bulk of the `GetCustomAttribute<IValidationRule>()` calls come from.

#### Unit Test

```
public void ValidatableBase_ValidationPerformanceTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var fixtures = new List<ValidatableFixture>();
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++)
    {
        var model = new ValidatableFixture();
        model.Name = "TestName";
        model.Password = "pass";
        model.PasswordConfirmation = "pass";
        fixtures.Add(model);
    }


    // Act
    foreach (ValidatableFixture fixture in fixtures)
    {
        fixture.ValidateAll();
    }

    watch.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

#### ValidatableFixture

```
public class ValidatableFixture : ValidatableBase
{
    private const string PasswordConfirmationDelegateName = "ConfirmPasswordsMatch";

    public ValidatableFixture()
    {
        this.Name = string.Empty;
        this.Password = string.Empty;
        this.PasswordConfirmation = string.Empty;
    }


    [ValidateValueIsNotNullOrEmpty(ValidationMessageType = typeof(MessageFixture), FailureMessage = "Name must be set.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [ValidateValueIsNotNullOrEmpty(ValidationMessageType = typeof(MessageFixture), FailureMessage = "Password must be set.")]
    [ValidateStringIsGreaterThan(GreaterThanValue = 4, ValidationMessageType = typeof(MessageFixture), FailureMessage = "Password must be greater than 4 characters.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    [ValidateWithCustomHandler(DelegateName = PasswordConfirmationDelegateName, ValidationMessageType = typeof(MessageFixture), FailureMessage = "Passwords do not match.")]
    public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }


    [ValidationCustomHandlerDelegate(DelegateName = PasswordConfirmationDelegateName)]
    public IMessage PasswordConfirmationValidation(IMessage message, PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return this.PasswordConfirmation.Equals(this.Password) ?
            null :
            message;
    }
}
```

Lastly, this is the base class that handles all of the validation.

#### ValidatableBase

```
public class ValidatableBase : IValidatable
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<IValidationRule>>> PropertyValidationCache
        = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<IValidationRule>>>();

    private Dictionary<string, ICollection<IMessage>> validationMessages;

    public ValidatableBase()
    {
        this.validationMessages = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<IMessage>>();
        this.SetupValidation();
    }

    public event EventHandler<ValidationChangedEventArgs> ValidationChanged;

    public void AddValidationMessage(IMessage message, string property)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("property", "You must supply a property name when adding a new validation message to this instance.");
        }

        // If the key does not exist, then we create one.
        if (!this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            this.validationMessages[property] = new List<IMessage>();
        }

        if (this.validationMessages[property].Any(msg => msg.Message.Equals(message.Message) || msg == message))
        {
            return;
        }

        this.validationMessages[property].Add(message);
    }

    public void RemoveValidationMessages()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ICollection<IMessage>> pair in this.validationMessages)
        {
            pair.Value.Clear();

            // Publish our new validation collection for this property.
            this.OnValidationChanged(new ValidationChangedEventArgs(pair.Key, this.validationMessages[pair.Key]));
        }
    }

    public void RemoveValidationMessages(string property)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(property) && this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            // Remove all validation messages for the property if a message isn't specified.
            this.validationMessages[property].Clear();
            this.OnValidationChanged(new ValidationChangedEventArgs(property, this.validationMessages[property]));
        }
    }

    public void RemoveValidationMessage(IMessage message, string property)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.validationMessages[property].Any(msg => msg == message || msg.Message.Equals(message.Message)))
        {
            // Remove the error from the key's collection.
            this.validationMessages[property].Remove(
                this.validationMessages[property].FirstOrDefault(msg => msg == message || msg.Message.Equals(message.Message)));

            this.OnValidationChanged(new ValidationChangedEventArgs(property, this.validationMessages[property]));
        }
    }

    public bool HasValidationMessages(string property = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property) || !this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            return this.validationMessages.Values.Any(collection => collection.Any());
        }

        return this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property) &&
            this.validationMessages[property].Any();
    }

    public bool HasValidationMessages(Type messageType, string property = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property) || !this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            return this.validationMessages.Values.Any(collection => collection.Any(item => item.GetType() == messageType));
        }

        return this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property) &&
            this.validationMessages[property].Any(collection => collection.GetType() == messageType);
    }

    public bool HasValidationMessages<TMessage>(string property = "") where TMessage : IMessage, new()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property) || !this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            return this.validationMessages.Values.Any(collection => collection.Any(item => item is TMessage));
        }

        return this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property) &&
            this.validationMessages[property].Any(message => message is TMessage);
    }

    public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IMessage>> GetValidationMessages()
    {
        var messages = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IMessage>>();

        // We have to iterate over the collection in order to conver the messages collection
        // from a ICollection type to an IEnumerable type.
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ICollection<IMessage>> pair in this.validationMessages)
        {
            messages.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        return messages;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IMessage> GetValidationMessages(string property)
    {
        if (this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            return this.validationMessages[property].ToArray();
        }

        // If no validation messages exist, return an empty collection.
        return new Collection<IMessage>();
    }

    public virtual void ValidateAll()
    {
        this.RemoveValidationMessages();
        Dictionary<PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<IValidationRule>> cache = PropertyValidationCache[this.GetType()];

        foreach (KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<IValidationRule>> pair in cache)
        {
            foreach (IValidationRule rule in pair.Value)
            {
                this.PerformValidation(rule, pair.Key);
            }

            // Publish our new validation collection for this property.
            this.OnValidationChanged(new ValidationChangedEventArgs(pair.Key.Name, this.validationMessages[pair.Key.Name]));
        }
    }

    public void ValidateProperty(string propertyName = "")
    {
        // If no property is provided, we assume we are to validate everything.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            this.ValidateAll();
            return;
        }

        this.RemoveValidationMessages(propertyName);
        var cache = ValidatableBase.PropertyValidationCache[this.GetType()];
        PropertyInfo property = cache.Keys.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(propertyName));

        foreach (IValidationRule rule in cache[property])
        {
            this.PerformValidation(rule, property);
        }

        this.OnValidationChanged(new ValidationChangedEventArgs(propertyName, this.validationMessages[propertyName]));
    }

    public IMessage ValidateProperty(Func<bool> validationDelegate, IMessage failureMessage, string propertyName, IValidatable validationProxy = null)
    {
        if (validationProxy != null)
        {
            return validationProxy.ValidateProperty(validationDelegate, failureMessage, propertyName);
        }

        bool passedValidation = validationDelegate();
        if (!passedValidation)
        {
            this.AddValidationMessage(failureMessage, propertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            this.RemoveValidationMessage(failureMessage, propertyName);
        }

        return !passedValidation ? failureMessage : null;
    }

    public void RefreshValidation(string property)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(property) && this.HasValidationMessages(property))
        {
            this.ValidateProperty(property);
        }
    }

    public void PerformValidation(IValidationRule rule, string property, IValidatable validationProxy = null)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("PerformValidation requires a registered property to be specified.");
        }
        else
        {
            propertyInfo = ValidatableBase.PropertyValidationCache[this.GetType()]
                .FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Key.Name.Equals(property)).Key;
        }

        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("PerformValidation requires a registered property to be specified.");
        }

        if (validationProxy != null && validationProxy is IValidatable)
        {
            var proxy = validationProxy as IValidatable;
            proxy.PerformValidation(rule, propertyInfo.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            IMessage result = rule.Validate(propertyInfo, this);
            if (result != null)
            {
                this.AddValidationMessage(result, propertyInfo.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnValidationChanged(ValidationChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        EventHandler<ValidationChangedEventArgs> handler = this.ValidationChanged;

        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, args);
    }

    private void RegisterProperty(params string[] propertyName)
    {
        foreach (string property in propertyName)
        {
            if (!this.validationMessages.ContainsKey(property))
            {
                this.validationMessages[property] = new List<IMessage>();
            }
        }
    }

    private void PerformValidation(IValidationRule rule, PropertyInfo property, IValidatable validationProxy = null)
    {
        if (validationProxy != null && validationProxy is ValidatableBase)
        {
            var proxy = validationProxy as ValidatableBase;
            proxy.PerformValidation(rule, property);
        }

        IMessage result = null;
        try
        {
            result = rule.Validate(property, this);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        if (result != null)
        {
            this.AddValidationMessage(result, property.Name);
        }
    }

    private void SetupValidation()
    {
        // We instance a cache of property info's and validation rules. If any other Type is instanced that matches ours,
        // we won't need to use reflection to obtain it's members again. We will just hit the cache.
        var cache = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<IValidationRule>>();

        if (!ValidatableBase.PropertyValidationCache.ContainsKey(this.GetType()))
        {
            IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertiesToValidate = this.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true).Any());

            // Loop through all property info's and build a collection of validation rules for each property.
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertiesToValidate)
            {
                IEnumerable<ValidationAttribute> rules = property
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true) as IEnumerable<ValidationAttribute>;
                cache.Add(property, rules);
            }

            ValidatableBase.PropertyValidationCache[this.GetType()] =
                new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<IValidationRule>>(cache);
        }
        else
        {
            cache = ValidatableBase.PropertyValidationCache[this.GetType()];
        }

        // Register each property for this instance once we are done caching.
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in cache.Keys)
        {
            this.RegisterProperty(property.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

The majority of the attribute rules don't use reflection to fetch additional validation attributes with the exception of the `ValidateWithCustomHandler` which does.

```
public sealed class ValidateWithCustomHandlerAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string DelegateName { get; set; }

    public override IMessage Validate(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property, IValidatable sender)
    {
        if (!this.CanValidate(sender))
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Create an instance of our validation message and return it if there is not a delegate specified.
        IMessage validationMessage = Activator.CreateInstance(this.ValidationMessageType, this.FailureMessage) as IMessage;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DelegateName))
        {
            return validationMessage;
        }

        // Find our delegate method.
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> validationMethods = sender
            .GetType()
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationCustomHandlerDelegate), true).Any());

        MethodInfo validationDelegate = validationMethods
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationCustomHandlerDelegate), true)
                .FirstOrDefault(del => (del as ValidationCustomHandlerDelegate).DelegateName == this.DelegateName) != null);

        // Attempt to invoke our delegate method.
        object result = null;
        try
        {
             result = validationDelegate.Invoke(sender, new object[] { validationMessage, property });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        // Return the results of the delegate method.
        if (result != null && result is IMessage)
        {
            return result as IMessage;
        }
        else if (result == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return validationMessage;
    }
}
```

If a sealed attribute is supposed to be quicker, why are my unit tests 10+% slower on average? Is my usage in the base class affecting the way attributes are fetched while sealed?

Comment: Your number of iterations is too small and you have no warmup calls (reflection does a crap load of caching) and you include too much code (ie setup code) in the actual test. Also, are any exceptions thrown? How was the test run?

Comment: In not sure I understand what you mean by to much setup in my test. Ive got less than a dozen lines to perform the set up. I don't see a need for a dedicated setup method if no other test uses the same code. I'll increase my iterations though. What do you mean by warm up calls? There were no exceptions thrown.

Comment: At least move stopwatch start after the setup loop. 40us is forever in terms of an iteration on a modern CPU.

Comment: I originally had the stop watch after the initial setup loop. It shaved 2-3ms off the overall time, so it wasn't much. The results were still the same though, with the unsealed attributes being faster than the sealed.

Comment: Make sure to call `fixture.ValidateAll()` at least once before starting the timing. I still think there is way too much code to make any assumptions.